# A riddle for everyone

Tags: riddle, word

So I have created another riddle for all riddle lovers. Might be easy for people out there but I want you guys to give me a correct explanation of each stanza.

> You find me attached to many things in life,
>   Many of you throw me out after using that thing.
>   
>   Replace a single character with one of mine,
>   I become an ancient language baby name for this rhyme.
>   
>   Break me into two continuous words,
>   Investigate in first with intensities of sound.
>   
>   Inside, I have a power and skill,
>   and a hollow object to will.

Hope you guys like it!

Have some hints to understand it more, in case.

Hint#1:

> You will found a baby name in that ancient language. Also, a holy book was earlier written in that language and a well-known country is using modern form of that language.

Hint#2:

> An example of continuous words. "Everyone" is a word and Every and One are the two continuous words but "evory" is not. Continuous words could have a common letter. In this riddle, continuous words will have the same length.

Hint#3:

> To complete the last stanza you need to rearrange the letters of the word.

Leave a comment in case you need help to understand anything. Guys, it is a word that most of us see during the shopping.

Comment: I guess Sanskrit is the language being referred and modern form of it is being used by Nepal.

Comment: That is by no means the only possibility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm trying to give this name to you, a

> label

You find me attached to many things in life, Many of you throw me out after using that thing.

> A label is a tag attached to a purchase giving information e.g. the instructions for use, and may be removed when using the object.

Replace a single character with one of mine, I become an ancient language baby name for this rhyme.

> Credit due to @Mea Culpa Nea this is Hebrew, the word may be *babel* which means confusing as in this riddle.
>  Hint 1: Book is the Bible, and the country Israel.

Break me into two continuous words, Investigate in first with intensities of sound.

> The two continuous words are lab and bel, of the same length and sharing a letter. 
>  A **lab** is a place made to investigate in, and a **bel** is a unit used to measure sound volume (more commonly a tenth of this is a decibel).

Inside, I have a power and skill,  and a hollow object to will.

> Rearrange the letters of the word **label**, the following are found inside, 
>   power and skill - **able** , hollow object to will - **bell**

Comment: Good catch :). Also, its LABAL (a baby name).

Answer (score 1):

Well, the words are

> DISCOUNT-SALES

and the explanation goes like this:

You find me attached to many things in life,
Many of you throw me out after using that thing.

> Many things in life are linked with selling and buying.

Many of you throw me out after using that thing.

> After using things (which are bought in discount sales!) we normally dispose

Replace a single character with one of mine,
I become an ancient language baby name for this rhyme.

> Replace last 'S' with 'M'- becoming SALEM, a Hebrew baby name, Hebrew being an ancient language

Break me into two continuous words,
Investigate in first with intensities of sound.

> **DISCO**UNT meets the required explanation for *intensities of sound*, perhaps.

Inside, I have a power and skill,
and a hollow object to will.

> To be provided ...

Comment: Well try! and got the correct language name. Unfortunately this is not an answer but you can find it nearby.